# Ionic 2 - Slider - show part of second slide item

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ion-slide-box

I want to show part of the second slide item, but don't know how to do it. This is what I have so far (basic Ionic slides):

```
<ion-slides pager >
            <ion-slide>
              <h2>Slide 1</h2>
            </ion-slide>

            <ion-slide>
              <h2>Slide 2</h2>
            </ion-slide>

            <ion-slide>
              <h2>Slide 3</h2>
            </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

and this is how I want it to be:
[image]

I've tried to change the width of the ion-slide to less than 100%, but the second and third slides just gets moved further to left, out of the screen.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Edit:- For **Ionic 5**
Set the Options in the TS file.

```
slideOpts = {
  slidesPerView: 1.5,
  spaceBetween: 10 
};
```

For **Ionic 3**

I think you get it. This solution for the others who are still searching for this view. Just add this to the ion-slides tag.

```
slidesPerView="1.5" spaceBetween="10"
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution indeed!

Comment: Simply Awesome :)

Comment: Thanks :) nice one

Comment: This is the correct answer in my opinion. I read the accepted answer and didn't read on... I struggled for a while only to come to this same conclusion.

Answer (score 6):

In UX, it is better for the user to know if he has more items to see, especially when we don't intend to use a pager.

`ion-slides` use internally http://www.idangero.us/swiper/ may this help us to accomplish that.

We can use `slidesPerView="2" spaceBetween="250"`

You have to refine the `spaceBetween` value according to your item slide size.

Lastly, you need an empty `ion-slide` in the end, because `spaceBetween` make a little mess in the positioning.

```
.card {
    width: 300px;
}

<ion-slides slidesPerView="2" spaceBetween="250">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let foo of bars">
        <my-item class="card"></my-item>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        <!-- need a empty slide to avoid last item to be inaccessible -->
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Comment: but how can you make it that the last slide has no spacing on the right so it wil fit correctly in the vieuw

Comment: slidesperview is giving complete next slide in current one. how to show only part of the next slide? @diego

Answer (score 4):

After wrestling with this issue, I found a pretty straightforward solution that seems to work.

```
<ion-slides spaceBetween="-18">
```

Obviously, adjust the number to match your specific needs.

Comment: I think this is a pretty bad solution. Diego's suggestion is definitely better, and certainly this is the right way. The solution to the problem is called slidesPerView. If you want, you can use of course spaceBetween additionally

Answer (score 3):

I had some good results setting the slidesPerView to 'auto' and giving each slide a margin-right of -18px and a margin-left of 18px (except for the first and last, of which either the margin-left and margin-right are set).

Here's the template code:

```
 <ion-slides [slidesPerView]="'auto'">
     <ion-slide *ngFor="...">
         ...
     </ion-slide>
 </ion-slides>
```

And here's the css:

```
  ion-slide {
    width: 240px !important;
    height: 290px !important;

    margin-right: -18px;
    margin-left: 18px
  }

  ion-slide:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  ion-slide:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution,

```
    <ion-slides pager="false" slidesPerView="1.2" spaceBetween="10" centeredSlides=true loop=true>

  <ion-slide>
    <h1 class="card">1</h1>
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide>
    <h1 class="card">2</h1>
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide>
    <h1 class="card">3</h1>
  </ion-slide>

</ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 2):

> IONIC 5

For similar type of scenario:

[image]

.ts

```
 slideOpts = {
    initialSlide: 1,
    speed: 400,
    slidesPerView: 1.2,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    centeredSlides: true
};
```

.html

```
<ion-slides [options]="slideOpts">
        <ion-slide>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" alt="" class="slider-img">
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" alt="" class="slider-img">
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200" alt="" class="slider-img">
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 0):

From Ionic 3, you can use 
`slidesPerView="2.5" spaceBetween="10"` in `ion-slides` tag , the `slidesPerView` can have any decimal values with single decimal digit. Adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I  managed to get this view , in ionic3.  It's a piece of cake. All you need is to set `slidesPerView= "auto"` then in your sass

```
ion-slide {
        width:80% !important;
        margin-top: 0px;}
```

[image: see the view]